# Reverse every word in a string and capitalize the start of the word

Tags: java, arrays, string, reverse

Sample input:

```
abc def ghi
```

Sample output:

```
Cba Fed Ihg
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StringRev {
    static String output1 = new String();
    static Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
    public static void ReverseString(String input) {
        input = input + " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            boolean cap = true;
            if (input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (cap) {
                        char c = stack.pop().charValue();
                        c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                        output1 = output1 + c;
                        cap = false;
                    } else
                        output1 = output1 + stack.pop().charValue();
                }
                output1 += " ";
            } else {
                stack.push(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.print(output1);
    }
}
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: I think this question belows to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @javaBeginner Should I ask it there as well or can I move it to codeReview. Also Is this a good implementation?

Comment: Don't use String to concat the results. Use StringBuilder to append the result values. Because String is immutable. Remove the String variable output1 and create a StringBuilder with in the reverseMethod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of

```
StringBuilder#reverse()
```

Then without adding any third party libraries,

```
    String originalString = "abc def ghi";
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : originalString.split(" ")) {
        String revStr = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
        revStr = Character.toUpperCase(revStr.charAt(0))
                + revStr.substring(1);
        resultBuilder.append(revStr).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(resultBuilder.toString());  //Cba Fed Ihg
```

[**Have a Demo**](https://ideone.com/mG6X0C)

Comment: stdin is 3 line input, for example, input = "2", "dog", "Cat", and it requires stdout, output = "God", "TaC". How to do Scanner,  do I need to use a list? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `StringBuffer` to [`reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#reverse%28%29) a string.

And then use the [`WordUtils#capitalize(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) method to make first letter of the string capitalized.

```
String str = "abc def ghi";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : str.split(" ")) {
    String revStr = new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
    sb.append(WordUtils.capitalize(revStr)).append(" ");
}
String strReversed = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**

Reverse the string first and make the first character to uppercase

```
String string="hello jump";
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(string," ") ;
String finalString ;

while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
   String input = str.nextToken() ;
   String reverse = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();
   System.out.println(reverse);

   String output = reverse .substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + reverse .substring(1);
   finalString=finalString+" "+output ;
}

System.out.println(finalString);
```

Comment: I think you didn't follow completely. Its not supposed to do `abc` to `Cba`. Rather its gotta do `abc def` to `Cba Fed`

Comment: Then you can `tokenize` the whole word and apply this above logic to each tokens.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct one, if it is  useful and simple to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String reverseString(final String input){
    if(null == input || isEmpty(input))
        return "";

    String result = "";
    String[] items = input.split(" ");

    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        result += new StringBuffer(items[i]).reverse().toString();
    }

    return result.substring(0,1).toupperCase() + result.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Reverse the String with this

```
StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("Java");
a.reverse();
```

2) To make First letter capital use
StringUtils class in apache commons lang package org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

It makes first letter capital

```
capitalise(String);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class CapatiliseAndReverse {
    public static void reverseCharacter(String input) {
        String result = "";
        StringBuilder revString = null;

        String split[] = input.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            revString = new StringBuilder(split[i]);
            revString = revString.reverse();

            for (int index = 0; index < revString.length(); index++) {

                char c = revString.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(revString.charAt(0))) {
                    revString.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }

                if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                    revString.setCharAt(index, Character.toLowerCase(c));
                }
            }

            result = result + " " + revString;
        }

        System.out.println(result.trim());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println(reverseCharacter("old is GlOd"));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        reverseCharacter(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```